# what is the correct behaviour of this csrrw

Tags: simulation, riscv

I am working with [RISCV Privileged 1.7 Instruction set](http://riscv.org/spec/riscv-privileged-spec-v1.7.pdf), Page 8 describes csrrw.

When the processor is executing :

```
csrrw   a0,cycle,a0
```

1. Should it update the "a0" register with CSR "cycle" value and also raise an exception as it is written in user mode?

or

2. Should it raise the exception and not update the CSR "cycle" register?

Comment: Please be elaborate. What is it? What have you tried? If convenient, show some code. Explain in detail.

Comment: @sharvil111 Well i am trying to work with RISCV previlidge instruction set v.1.9. I was wondering what is the right way the this instruction should behave?

Comment: riscv-privileged is at 1.7, compressed is at 1.9 but does not contain csrrw. Have added link in question to the privileged 1.7 spec to help clarify the question if this is the wrong version can you edit the question to link to the correct documentation.

Comment: thanks @Morgan indeed it is for 1.7 version. I was asking it for privileged instruction set v1.7

Answer (score 0):

The RISC-V [Privileged Architecture](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual) document specifies that `cycle` is a read-only CSR and thus any write to it should yield an illegal instruction exception.

> Attempts to access a CSR without appropriate privilege level or **to write a read-only register** also raise illegal instruction exceptions.

(emphasis mine, Section 2.1 CSR Address Mapping Conventions, page 5, [The RISC-V Instruction Set Manual. Volume II: Privileged Architecture](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual). 1.12-draft)

The specification leaves it unspecified what happens to the destination register if an illegal instruction exception is raised because of a write to an read-only CSR.

That means whether an implementation writes the destination register or not it is conforming to the specification as long as it raises an illegal instruction exception.

Answer (score 0):

the format of the csrrw is:

```
csrrw    rd,csr,rs1
```

so, you are trying to do

```
R[rd]=CSR; CSR=R[rs1]
this means  
R[a0]=cycle; cycle=R[a0]
```

this has a problem "cycle" is a read-only CSR. You can use mcycle instead, mcycle has a ramdom value but you can overwrite it.

```
csrrw a0, mcycle, a0
```